# TS (7015) Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript

In an angular project the code [image]The following script in movie.service.ts cause error ts(7015) Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: `Movie[]` is an array of `Movie`s. It has no `"Search"`.

Comment: Movie[] is an array, but you are accessing the property `Search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the module.ts file was not properly updated. After the updates - the app worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confusing the `map` rxjs function with the `map` array method.

The `map` function in `rxjs` map every value emitted from an observable. If you want every value emitted from the observable to be mapped to a property, you need to **also** use `Array.prototype.map`:

```
map(res => res.map(item => item.Search))
```

Comment: The supporting text states that 'the API results are wrapped in an array 'Search' of the result-object. the results must be unwrapped in the Service. the map() method is to be used for this in the pipeline of the Service.

Comment: I suppose you're talking about an internal API, you shouldn't be searching help here on SO :)

Comment: No- it is an external API: http://www.omdbapi.com/ we is used to test and learn angular. I figured out that the module.ts file was not properly updated. After the updates - the app worked.